# How do I wire a receptacle and a light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I saw one of your posts with diagrams and I figured that is exactly what I need.   I have a GFCI outlet and light switch in the same box.   There are 2 sets of wires coming from the wall(Blk, wht, grnd).  The first set is live and feeds the outlet (LINE)   The 2nd set comes from the lamp on the wall and into the box where the light switch will go.  How do I do the wiring so the light switch will have power??

Comment: Of course, before doing any electrical work, turn the power off!

Answer (score 3):

Use a wire nut to connect together:

1. The live black wire
2. The hot LINE terminal on the outlet
3. One terminal on the switch

Use a wire nut to connect together:

1. The live white wire
2. The neutral LINE terminal on the outlet
3. The white wire coming from the lamp on the wall

Connect the other terminal on the switch to the black wire coming from the lamp on the wall.

Lastly, use a wire nut to connect together:

1. The ground wire from the live cable
2. The ground wire from the lamp cable
3. The ground terminals on the outlet and switch
4. The ground nut in the box, if this is a metal box.

Bad diagram follows:

[image]

Comment: Your switch/light shows no switch leg that could be a little confusing to those who don't know what they are looking at.